# python irc bot ping answer

Tags: python, irc

I'm trying to write a simple IRC bot in Python. My bot would connect to a server, join a channel and then print to the console the messages received by the bot. 
I did it, but the server always disconnects me after a while because of ping timeout. I tried to use some libraries (python-irc and oyoyo) and they both ALLEGEDLY handle automatically the ping-pong messages with the server. But I tried with irc.abjects.net and irc.criten.net and with both of them these libraries failed.
Then I made a script based on this one: http://hawkee.com/snippet/9725/. And it failed too. So... I suppose the problem is very stupid and simple, but I jsut can't figure out a solution.

Note: with the library irc3 the ping-pong works fine, but it uses asyncio, which conflicts with some other parts of my code (not related to irc). So I can't use it.

Comment: What question are you asking? I don't see a '?' anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was obvious. How can I do a bot that correctly catch the ping messages from the server and correctly answer? Related to the servers I mentioned in the question (because  http://hawkee.com/snippet/9725/ handles the ping messages, but not with criten and abjects - with those servers it doesn't even catch the ping messages)

Comment: You always need to answer a `PING` with a pong, even if you do heavy processing at the time.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn you're right, but I found out my problem was different. Some servers instead of sending pings to you, they want you to send a periodic ping to them. I wasn't aware of this behavior, which was exactly the root of my problems. So, problem solved.